# How do I set up a route in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my routes.rb I have this:

```
 map.namespace :admin do |admin|
       admin.resources :galleries do |galleries|
          galleries.resources :gallery_images, :as=>'images'
       end
 end
```

rake routes shows the route created like this:

```
 admin_gallery GET    /admin/galleries/:id
```

and when I go to this url in my browser:

```
http://192.168.2.2:3000/admin/galleries/11
```

I get this error:

```
Unknown action
No action responded to 11
```

But I would have expected it to use the show action/view, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post your entire routes page. Something else in it is interfering.

Comment: We're going to need the whole routes.rb. Could you gist it?
There could be something like :controller/:action/:id above the namespaced portion you're providing that is interfering, as @fig-gnuton mentioned.

Comment: Have you restarted your server after adding the route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routes higher up in the file can interfere with this, and did. Tim Snowhite's comment was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing slash and it should work for you

```
http://192.168.2.2:3000/admin/galleries/11
```

Comment: That's a drag. Does the error message you get say what controller it went to?  And does that match what rake routes printed out?